# Accessing private variable from a friend class - I believe my syntax is wrong

Tags: c++, class, simulator, friend

Okay, so this is a parking ticket application... I'm sure you've all seen/done them before. This one is for C++ and I'm having trouble with getting my class-contained methods to access private members of a friend class. I know that this is completely a syntax error, but I can't seem to find an example that makes sense to me on what the syntax actually is.

This is (one of) the lines that I get errors on. They're all the same error,

```
    cout<<"Please visit your local police department issued by "<<policeOfficer.name<<" badge number "<<policeOfficer.badgeNumber <<" to pay your $"<<fine<<" fine.";
```

And here is the beginning of the policeOfficer class, in case I haven't appropriately declared friend status between the classes.

```
class policeOfficer
{
private:
string name, badgeNumber;
public:
friend class parkedCar;
friend class parkingMeter;
friend class parkingTicket;
```

There's a couple of errors. "error C2027: use of undefined type"
"left of '.badgeNumber' must have class/struct/union"
"type name not allowed"
"identifier createTicket is undefined"

But they all center around that single line of code, plus a few others that I have written the same exact way.

Sorry if I've missed anything necessary, I'd be more than happy to provide more information if I did.

Comment: What error? I see no error.

Comment: Probably you meant `friend class parkedCar;`, etc.

Comment: Adding the "class" keyword got rid of a few errors - I actually had it in my other friend declarations just apparently missed it there. :/ Thanks

Comment: Also, `policeOfficer` is the **name** of a class, not an object that exists in memory. You need to instantiate an object first, i.e. `policeOfficer p; p.name;`. Instead of guessing the syntax, I recommend [reading some books on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that teach you this.

Comment: I've read the chapter in my C++ book twice through before asking here, actually. I can't find a specific example for accessing variables and not methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

policeOfficer is name of a class and you are trying to access a private member variable using class name so it is giving error. Create an object of **policeOfficer obj** and then access the variable obj.badgenumber.

Comment: Forgot to set up the access from the main. No wonder they wouldn't interact! Thanks. I've got the errors whittled down considerably now.